# How to find the column value with the biggest storage size in the DB?

Tags: postgresql, postgresql-9.6, size

Is there any way to find out which column value has the largest storage out of all tables in PostgreSQL DB?

I'm looking for currently used storage, [`information_schema.column`](https://www.postgresql.org/docs/9.6/infoschema-columns.html) only shows the length of the datatype. Looking for something like `max(pg_column_size())`.

Comment: Yes, but if you multiple the cardinality of the table, with the largest column you should be able to nail down the suspects

Comment: The largest single value or looking at the total size of a column (the sum from all table rows)?

Comment: @Erwin, looking for the largest single value.